# IntelliJ not recognising the mock method in JUnitRuleMockery

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I was re-doing some university tutorials in the lead up to exams and ran into a problem. IntelliJ believes that all the relevant JUnit4 details are in the class path but will not recognise the `mock` method in the code below:

```
  import org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnitRuleMockery;
  import org.junit.Rule;
  import org.junit.Test;

  ...

  @Rule
  public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

  Sensor sensor = context.mock(Sensor.class);

  Camera camera = new Camera();

  ...
```